# Multiplying the ToString value in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, int, tostring

I've created a code that gets the localscale value and transforms it into a string. Supposedly, it should change its unit of measurement to centimeters by multiplying it to 10. Problem is, trying to multiply the value in a string does not work since it's a string afterall. I've also planned trying to convert it into string but unfortunately I became more confused instead. Are there any ways to add/subtract/multiply the localscale value that I've converted into string? Here's my vanilla code without formulas.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using UnityEngine.UI;

 public class ScaleSlider : MonoBehaviour {

     public Slider sliderLength;
     public Slider sliderWidth;
     public Slider sliderHeight;
     public Text textLength;
     public Text textWidth;
     public Text textHeight;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         sliderWidth.value = 1f;
         sliderLength.value = 1f;
         sliderHeight.value = 1f;
     }

     void Update () {
         textLength.text = transform.localScale.x.ToString();
         textWidth.text = transform.localScale.y.ToString();
         textHeight.text = transform.localScale.z.ToString();
         transform.localScale = new Vector3(sliderLength.value*1, sliderWidth.value*1, sliderHeight.value*1);

     }

 }
```

Comment: `int.Parse(string)`

Comment: You mean: (transform.localScale.x * 10).ToString(); ?

Comment: Thank you rvdk. Definitely what I needed :) sadly I'm not able to vote your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to convert it back into a numerical `Type` first.
Try:

```
float.Parse(transform.localScale.x.ToString()) *= 10f;
```

Or, if what you are trying to achieve is to multiply it and **then** convert it to a string you could try:

```
(transform.localScale.x * 10f).ToString();
```